# Selecting MySQL row during Batch Update

Tags: mysql, etl

I currently have a database with 500K rows that could grow to 3 million in the future. The structure of the table looks like the following:

-id 
-price 
-sku 
-version (denoted by a Date Time string ie. 20211012)

I have an ETL job that will update the price and version columns nightly with only UPDATE statements and no INSERTs and DELETEs. My issue is that in order to show the item, I need to query by the sku and version. Before the ETL job runs everything is OK. But when the ETL job starts to update rows in batches the version changes and I am no longer able to SELECT that particular sku due to a version mismatch.

My idea to solve this problem is to keep track of the previous and current version executed by the ETL job (ie. 20211012 and 20211013) in order to try and select the current version if the record has been updated or fall back to the previous version if the ETL job has not updated that particular object.

Are there any pitfalls I should be aware of? What would happen if I were to perform a SELECT on a particular record that was concurrently being updated by the ETL job?

Comment: If you need to store the history then you must forget about UPDATE and DELETE. You must INSERT new rows with new data state. Insertion datetime should define actual state for each entity at any needed datetime point.

Comment: @Akina: Thank you for the insight. I am only trying to guarantee that there will be a price for that particular object.

Comment: How many old versions do you need to keep?  Perhaps you only need to keep the current version and one previous?  Is the problem that there is some kind of lock during the Update and it is preventing the Select from finishing?

Comment: @RickJames: I only need to keep 1 version of the price. I was thinking I could just keep 1 version by performing an update. I have not implemented this solution yet, but I was concerned that there would be some sort of lock that would occur during the update that would prevent the select. Would you know a way around that problem?

Comment: Do you Update _all_ rows each time?  Do you ever need to add _new_rows?

Comment: @RickJames: Its possible that all rows or just a subset of them will be updated each time. Sometimes new rows are added if there are new items that not present from before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ...;  -- to hold the day's updates
LOAD DATA ...; -- into that table
massage the data if anything needs 'fixing'
INSERT INTO real_table (col1, ...)
    SELECT col1, ...
        FROM temp_table
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        ...;
```

All done in one pass.  Handles Inserts, Updates, (but not deletes)

If that blocks usage of the table too long, see the following for chunking the upsert step:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks

Comment: Thank you this seems like a very sensible approach. Could you explain why it would be beneficial to insert into a temporary table and move the data from there to the real table instead of just inserting directly into the real table? What would happen if I were to try and select a particular row that was being updated at the same time?

Comment: @Student - `LOAD DATA` cannot do the "upsert", only `INSERT`.  Also, it gives you a chance to look at the data to see if it looks good and/or to fix things.  `SELECTing` any row would be OK; `UPDATEing` a row would be blocked.  The blocking would be only a short time if you use the chunking that I suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Stale data is the worst case, realistically. May want to review the [transaction isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html) and properly configure your instance to best suit what you can handle. In this case, repeatable-read may be a solid start and batch your updates into single row statements. You can batch them by 10k rows at a time.